# Maya batch render missing alpha channel

Tags: animation-rendering, nuke, compositing, maya, alpha

I'm trying to export a scene to composite in Nuke.  When I "render current frame" and save the image from there, I get an image with an alpha channel, but when I batch render the images don't have the alpha channel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to say. In general your _beauty pass_ should contain the alpha. Bmp is very limited, try to render as exr. Also check if _Pass Custom Alpha Channel checkbox_ is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem after some more trial and error. For awhile it looked like the fact that I was using Mental Ray shaders combined with general shaders was the problem, but that didn't really make sense so I kept tweaking. It turns out that an image plane I had tied to my camera was the problem. The image on the plane never rendered out, so I assumed the plane wasn't affecting the rendering, but it turns out it was showing up as a black plane when rendered. I deleted the plane for my render and it works fine now.